# How to implement a tooltip that supports HTML?

Tags: css, angular

I'm using angular material, which has a neat tooltip, but it's not supporting HTML. So basically, just like a regular tooltip, when I hover over an element I want the contents of a component to appear on the right/left/top/bottom (wherever there is enough space available).

How can do that?

Comment: Did you know http://istarkov.github.io/html-hint/#exampleMain ?

Comment: You can create this behaviour with the material CDK overlay with a `ConnectedPositionStrategy`, see https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

Comment: Both your answers are viable solutions. I will try out both. Thank you very much.